# phpMyAdmin - Can't Access Root

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a crisis on my hands. I was using phpMyAdmin and then, I added an account with the credentials (let's say):

- host: (any),
- username: root
- password: example123
- permissions: all

Then, I accidentally created another user:

- host: localhost,
- username: root
- password: example123
- permissions: none

Also, I accidentally deleted all the other accounts so those are the only accounts that can login. Whenever I login, I go into the no permissions account because I can't do anything.

More information: I am running this server on a Raspberry Pi through an ethernet cable.

**Please help me! I will be grateful for any answers and I am in the middle of a project so I need help soon. Thank you so much!**

Answer (score 0):

Call phpmyadmin by using the internal IP of your Raspberry Pi instead of localhost. So if you login you must have all permissions.

Comment: This did something to help, but it did not completely fix the problem.

Comment: If you have all permisions you can chance them for the localhost root as well. What is the problem you want to fix.